# After disabling swap memory for Docker container, but I can still see lots of swap used in my process, why?

Tags: docker

I am running some pods (Solr & Zookeeper) on AWS EC2.

Though k8s does not promote swap by default, I still enabled it by setting **--fail-swap-on** to false cause I want my system to be able to use swap. And then I found some strange behaviors on swap usage which I hope you could help shed some light on :)

According to Docker [doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details), we can restrict Docker containers from using swap memory by doing the following.

> If --memory-swap is set to the same value as --memory, and --memory is
>   set to a positive integer, the container does not have access to swap.
>   See Prevent a container from using swap.

With `docker inspect`, I can see:

- `MemorySwappiness` is set to null, so it just uses the params set on
  the OS.

  `Memory` equals `MemorySwap`, so no swap memory could be used.

  ```
  $ sudo docker inspect 30309d07aa95 | grep Mem
      "Memory": 1073741824,
      "CpusetMems": "",
      "KernelMemory": 0,
      "MemoryReservation": 0,
      "MemorySwap": 1073741824,
      "MemorySwappiness": null,
  ```

However, after running my container for a while, I can see my Solr is using a lot of swap.

```
$ grep --color VmSwap /proc/9549/status
VmSwap:   261812 kB
```

and meanwhile, about 517820 kB physical memory is used.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work as described in Docker's document?

### Other Info

- OS: Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0cbc6aae997c6538a (64-bit x86) / ami-09172771b47695ce2
- Docker version

  Client:
   Version:           18.06.3-ce
   API version:       1.38
   Go version:        go1.10.3
   Git commit:        d7080c1
   Built:             Wed Feb 20 02:26:51 2019
   OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
   Experimental:      false

  Server:
   Engine:
    Version:          18.06.3-ce
    API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
    Go version:       go1.10.3
    Git commit:       d7080c1
    Built:            Wed Feb 20 02:28:17 2019
    OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
    Experimental:     false
- Some system settings about memory

  vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0

  vm.overcommit_memory = 1

  vm.overcommit_ratio = 50

  vm.swappiness = 60

  vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100

Comment: If you care about Java applications and Docker, you should definitively review this excellent article: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/

Comment: @Gerrit thanks! I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Because not all swap is created equal.  `VmSwap` accounts for things other than what you might be thinking of as "swap", including dirty pages from memory-mapped files -- and IIRC, Solr does like itself some mmap'd files.  `/proc/<pid>/smaps` should give more detail as to exactly what's going on.

Comment: Hi I ran the command, and it listed lots of information. What should I look for?

Comment: One of the entries still shows:

Swap:             227848 kB
SwapPss:          227848 kB